# Testing the forward and rewind in android emulator

Tags: java, android-studio, android-emulator, android-testing, android-tv

In many Android-TVs, we have media rewind and media forward buttons in their remote. But in the android-tv emulator's remote we have the directional pad, home and back press. 
Is there any way to debug the forward and rewind button with the emulator itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context menu, if you select 'Directional pad', there is a play/pause, rewind, and fast forward button.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't shows in the linux version of Android Studio. Otherwise I wouldn't have asked this in the first place. Thanks!

Comment: I was wondering why you were not seeing it :) 
If you are expecting to have these buttons, like in the screen shot, then you can file a bug. 
Look for "Emulator or System Images" for more details --> https://source.android.com/source/report-bugs